# How can I execute multiple EF Core save changes in different services within a single transaction?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

In my app I have a [Mediatr](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) handler which has a `DBContext` and 2 services injected via DI. Each of these services have their own `DBContext` also injected via DI.

> Is there a way for me to execute all of the work carried out in the handler and services within a single EF Core transaction?

The only way I can think of doing this would be for the handler to new up each service and pass it's instance of the `DBContext` to each and call `SaveChanges` at the end of the handler. This would work but I'm wondering if there's a better way where I don't have to instantiate each service myself.

Comment: You may initiate a transaction from one context and use it for the other context, then commit once. But before that maybe it is a better idea to think if spliting the context is really a correct decision for your use case or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the Unit Of Work-pattern. In this, you create a Unit of Work object that has a reference to your DbContext. Everywhere, you inject your Unit Of Work instead of your DbContext. Since this is the same object within the same scope, all of your services will use the same DbContext reference as well. A call to `SaveChanges()` will then affect multiple tables at once as well.

This seems like a good link: https://cpratt.co/repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making a singleton handler that you inject into the services.

What you want to do is something you **must not**!  First, operations that spread across multiple services tend to take time, meaning you will have your transaction open for a while.  Second, if the client breaks and doesn't complete the chain of operations, your transaction will stay open.  Third, you will have hard time to cope with concurrent operations.

A better possible approach will be to simulate a transaction by storing your data with a temporary flag, that at the end you clear, or that you use to delete records in case you need to rollback.